# How to change from one stylesheet to another with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, stylesheet

I want to change the style of a page between two different .css files when the user clicks a link.

When the link is clicked, I want the new style to be loaded. When it is clicked a second time, I want the default style to be loaded. (In other words, I want to be able to toggle between two different stylesheets on a click event).

```
$(function(){
   $('.default').click(function(){
      $('#link').attr('href', 'defaultStyle' );
      $('.default').addClass('new').removeClass('default');
   });

});
$(function(){
   $('.new').click(function(){
      $('#link').attr('href', 'secondStyle' );
      $('.new').addClass('default').removeClass('new');
   });
});
```

The code above changed the style once, but the second block doesn't work.

How can I fix this? TIA.

Comment: second block shouldn't read:  $('.new').addClass('default').removeClass('NEW');  ??

Comment: I think it should be `$('.new').addClass('default').removeClass('new');` in your second block since you add `new` class in first block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('.new').live('click',function(){});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

```
  $('.new').addClass('default').removeClass('reader');
```

Supposed to be:

```
  $('.new').addClass('default').removeClass('new');
```

Also, have you checked firefox / fiddler / etc to see if the browser is trying to download the second stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

The click handlers are assigned to the elements that currently exist. `.new` does not exist yet when you execute the second block (only after you clicked `.default`).

Just toggle the classes:

```
$(function(){
   $('.default').click(function(){
      $('#link').attr('href', function(i, v) {
           return v === 'defaultStyle' ? 'secondStyle' : 'defaultStyle';
      });

      $(this).toggleClass('new').toggleClass('default');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the jQuery selector is only finding elements with .new when the JavaScript is first executed.

You should look into jQuery.live() http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with jquery, here is an example,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#blue').click(function(event) {
    $('#text').css('background-color','blue');
  });

  $('#grey').click(function(event) {
    $('#text').css('background-color','grey');
  });

});
<div id="text" style="background-color:grey;" >Hello World</div>
<div id="blue" style="cursor:pointer" >blue</div>
<div id="grey" style="cursor:pointer" >grey</div>
```